# Routing all requests from different domain to index.php with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've set up a site which uses .htaccess for all URL rewrites, but now i'm trying to set it up so that any domain can be pointed at the site via CNAME record, which works like a charm, heres an example:

mainsite.com - is the site

test.somesite.com points to mainsite.com/index.php

However when you visit test.somesite.com/test it shows 404 because the rewrite rule/directory does not exist. Is there a way to make it in .htaccess so that if the domain is not the main domain, all the traffic points to index.php?